# Label for a compare (except query) in SAS

Tags: sas

hi I'm running the below. 
1st query comes back with what I need... I just wanted to add a column to know the inviroment of the object. the 2nd query doesn't work cuz its looking at the 'P' and 'T' column and comparing that

## 1)

```
proc sql;
create table ALL_compare_PROD_TEST as 
(select * from PROD Except select * from TEST)
UNION ALL 
(select  * from TEST Except select * from PROD)

ORDER BY code ASC

;QUIT;
```

## 2)

```
proc sql;
create table ALL_compare_PROD_TEST as 
(select 'P'as PROD, * from PROD Except select * from TEST)
UNION ALL 
(select 'T'as TEST, * from TEST Except select * from PROD)

ORDER BY code ASC

;QUIT;
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you just need another level of subquery. Also you will want the P and T to be in the same variable.

```
proc sql;
create table ALL_compare_PROD_TEST as 
  select 'P' as SRC,* from (select * from PROD except select * from TEST)
  UNION ALL 
  select 'T' as SRC,* from (select * from TEST except select * from PROD)
  ORDER BY code ASC
;
quit;
```